# async/await in forEach loop

Tags: javascript

The below JavaScript is returning a strange version of an array. The below forEach logs nothing to console. I'm probably missing something quite fundamental here, but I know for a fact that the array is populated...unless it's not populated until later due to being async and Chrome just evaluates the console.log after the fact?

```js
let damageRollStringArr = []

monster.damage_types.forEach(async (damageTypeName) => {
    const damageType = await checkResponseAndReturnValue(await DamageTypesService.findDamageType(damageTypeName.trim()))

    if (damageType !== null) {
        damageRollStringArr.push(damageType.damage)
    }
})

damageRollStringArr.forEach(el => console.log(el))

// Was returning an empty array[] with objects inside?
return damageRollStringArr
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

demageRollStringArr.forEach (2nd foreach) wont wait for monster.demage_types.forEach (1st foreach) to execute although there is async await in the first forEach

To achieve what you want to do, try this,

```
let damageRollStringArr = []
const promises = monster.damage_types.map(async (damageTypeName) => {
    const damageType = await checkResponseAndReturnValue(await DamageTypesService.findDamageType(damageTypeName.trim()))
    if (damageType !== null) {
        damageRollStringArr.push(damageType.damage)
    }
})
await Promise.all(promises)
damageRollStringArr.forEach(el => console.log(el))
return damageRollStringArr
```

Or, you can use normal for() loop to replace 1st foreach

```
let damageRollStringArr = []
for(let i = 0; i < monster.demage_types.length; i++) {
    const damageType = await checkResponseAndReturnValue(await DamageTypesService.findDamageType(damageTypeName.trim()))
    if (damageType !== null) {
        damageRollStringArr.push(damageType.damage)
    }
}
damageRollStringArr.forEach(el => console.log(el))
return damageRollStringArr
```

1st solution will run the loop parallel,
2nd solution will run the loop sequential

Comment: Thanks for this, LHJ. I thought there was an issue with the data I was being returned from a response call, not the forEach function having an issue with async await calls. I've now done reading up this: I need to understand forEach a whole lot better than I currently do.